# While trying to mint NFTs from Hardhat to Polygon Mainnet using JS script getting error ProviderError: HttpProviderError

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hardhat

I am trying to mint nfts using js script but I get this vague error **ProviderError: HttpProviderError** I have deployed my contract on polgonscan mainnet.
I have tested this script on the polygon test network Mumbai and works perfectly fine but on the mainnet, it gives an error. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

My minting script is:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/MintNFT.sol/MintNFT.json");
const contractInterface = contract.abi;
let provider = ethers.provider;
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
wallet.provider = provider;
const signer = wallet.connect(provider);

const id = 1; // id of the nft to be minted
const amount = 2500; // number of times nft should be minted

async function main() {
  try {
    const mintContract = new ethers.Contract(
      process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      contractInterface,
      signer
    );
    await mintContract.functions.mint(id, amount);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  }
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

This is my hardhat config which I used to deploy contract on mainnet

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  defaultNetwork: "matic",
  networks: {
    mumbai: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
    matic: {
      url: "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/tDq9iU4BH3fEusvjSlbuOHiJhSuBHM_1",
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: As you said it seems to be working fine everywhere else and emitting the provider error on mainnet only, I guess it has something to do with the alchemy endpoint, try using this `https://rpc.ankr.com/polygon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set gasLimit of transaction:

```js
await mintContract.functions.mint(id, amount, { gasLimit: 40000000 });
```